# Oracle Function In Package Fails as Part of Select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I call my function from my package like the following, it works. It is a bit complex but there are a lot of conditional variable.

```
resultval := TG_PKG_ENTITY_TOTAL.user_entity_total('0012345678',
    '01-JUL-1955','30-JUN-2013',amounttype,accountrec,deptrec,appealrec,
    allocschoolrec,isunrestricted,pledge_exclude,pledgetypes_exclude,
    honormem_exclude) ;
```

If I try to use it as part of a select statement, it does **not** work. Any ideas how to fix this? I think it may have to do with the external references to custom data type. But I would think the first example would fail also but it works.

The following fails.

```
SELECT e.id_number,TG_PKG_ENTITY_TOTAL.user_entity_total(e.id_number,
    '01-JUL-1955','30-JUN-2013',amounttype,accountrec,deptrec,appealrec,
    allocschoolrec,isunrestricted,pledge_exclude,pledgetypes_exclude,
    honormem_exclude) AS SoftCredit
FROM advance.entity e
```

*FAIL means that it raises **error 6550 wrong number or type of argument**

**The following types are defined in a package called TG_PKG_TYPES**

```
TYPE string_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500);

TYPE account_rec IS RECORD
(condition VARCHAR2(20), 
 account_array string_array);

TYPE dept_rec IS RECORD
(condition VARCHAR2(20), 
 dept_array string_array);

TYPE allocschool_rec IS RECORD
(condition VARCHAR2(20), 
 school_array string_array);

 TYPE appeal_rec IS RECORD
(condition VARCHAR2(20), 
 appeal_array string_array);



 TYPE amounttype_rec IS RECORD
 (GiftAmt                BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  GiftCreditAmt          BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  PaymentAmt             BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  PayCreditAmt           BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  CompanyMatch           BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  EmployeeMatch          BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  EmpSpouseMatch         BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  EmpMatchClaim          BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  EmpSpouseMatchClaim    BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  PledgeAmt              BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
  PledgeCreditAmt        BOOLEAN :=FALSE);
```

**FUNCTION PARAMS:**

```
FUNCTION user_entity_total( id_number VARCHAR2 := NULL,
                            i_start_date VARCHAR2 :=NULL, 
                            i_end_date VARCHAR2 :=NULL,
                            i_amount_type tu_pkg_types.amounttype_rec :=NULL,
                            i_account IN tu_pkg_types.account_rec :=NULL,
                            i_dept IN tu_pkg_types.dept_rec :=NULL,
                            i_appeal IN  tu_pkg_types.appeal_rec :=NULL,
                            i_allocschool IN  tu_pkg_types.allocschool_rec :=NULL,
                            i_isunrestricted CHAR :=NULL,
                            i_excludepledge BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
                            i_excludepledgetypes BOOLEAN :=FALSE,
                            i_excludehonormem BOOLEAN :=FALSE) RETURN NUMBER;
```

Comment: Please define "Fails". What error message?

Comment: Are `amounttype` etc. columns on `entity`? Where are the custom data types, and where are they defined - in the package? Oh yes, and what's the error you get?

Comment: The data types are defined in a separate package. see update

Comment: What is the type of `id_number` in `advance.entity`?

Comment: Is your `select` in PL/SQL too then, as a cursor since there is no `into`? With the variables used as parameters defined exactly the same, from that other package? Might be helpful to show the function spec, particulary the return type, and also maybe show more context of what you're passing in.

Comment: The SELECT routine is a select statement inside a PL/SQL anonymous block. It is simply a test page to see if the function works properly as part of a select. I can call other custom functions from the select but the difference is that these other functions are not part of a package and does not have records as a type for the parameters.

Comment: id_number is varchar2(10)

Comment: I added function parameters to the examples above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot call functions that have PL/SQL records as arguments (or return type) from SQL (since you can only use schema-level types from SQL; the same applies for collection types).

Try declaring an object type (at schema level) and using that as parameter for your function instead.

Comment: It doesn't like the `boolean` types either, also because they're PL/SQL only. I wanted to check because the error seems slightly odd, but it's definitely those. The `amounttyperec` type will be a problem with your approach though since you can't use `boolean` in an object either, for the same reason again. Maybe you could do a wrapper function to do the conversion from native types to package types but it wouldn't be too pretty.